# Ошибки получаю, Spring jpa

Tags: java, spring-jpa

хотел практиковаться на Spring jpa. Сделал POJO класс с аннотациями Entity, ID и GeneratedValue и затем создал интерфейс наследуя от CrudRepository и создал класс, который запускает приложение, однако я ловлю почему то ошибку якобы бин не создан. Погуглил решение, ни одно решение не помог. Подскажите, что мне нужно добавить?
Customer:

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    
    protected Customer () {}
    
    public Customer (String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.setFirstname(firstname);
        this.setLastname(lastname);
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

CustomerRepository:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
    List<Customer> findByLastName (String lastName);
}
```

Класс, который запускает приложение:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication (exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        CustomerRepository repository = context.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);
        
        repository.save(new Customer ("John", "Smith"));
        repository.save(new Customer ("Mike", "Smith"));
        repository.save(new Customer ("test2", "test3"));
        
        Iterable<Customer> iterable = repository.findAll();
        
        System.out.println("Iterable with method findAll ()");
        
        for (Customer customer : iterable) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        
        List<Customer> list = repository.findByLastName("Smith");
        
        System.out.println("List with method findByLastName");
        
        for (Customer customer : list) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        
        context.close(); 
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-ri</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Ошибки:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v3.1.2)[0;39m

[2m2023-08-10T22:39:40.491+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.example.demo.DemoApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 10436 (C:\Users\qweac\eclipse-workspace\demo\target\classes started by AcerNitro5 in C:\Users\qweac\eclipse-workspace\demo)
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:40.493+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.example.demo.DemoApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:40.709+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:40.737+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 23 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:40.913+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:40.944+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.7.Final
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:40.946+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.cfg.Environment           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.031+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.107+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.119+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.206+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@1d98daa0
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.207+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.238+03:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.orm.deprecation           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.359+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.709+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.736+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.896+03:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository' defined in com.example.demo.CustomerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CustomerRepository.findByLastName(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CustomerRepository.findByLastName(java.lang.String); No property 'lastName' found for type 'Customer'; Did you mean 'lastname'
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.896+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.897+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.902+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.907+03:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2023-08-10T22:39:41.918+03:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m10436[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository' defined in com.example.demo.CustomerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CustomerRepository.findByLastName(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CustomerRepository.findByLastName(java.lang.String); No property 'lastName' found for type 'Customer'; Did you mean 'lastname'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CustomerRepository.findByLastName(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CustomerRepository.findByLastName(java.lang.String); No property 'lastName' found for type 'Customer'; Did you mean 'lastname'
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CustomerRepository.findByLastName(java.lang.String); No property 'lastName' found for type 'Customer'; Did you mean 'lastname'
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:124) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:258) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'lastName' found for type 'Customer'; Did you mean 'lastname'
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:405) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:334) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:316) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:299) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:242) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:372) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сообщении об ошибке указано:

> `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository' defined in com.example.demo.CustomerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CustomerRepository.findByLastName(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CustomerRepository.findByLastName(java.lang.String); No property 'lastName' found for type 'Customer'; Did you mean 'lastname'`

То есть поле в классе `Customer` названо `lastname` (все буквы маленькие), а в репозитории используется имя `lastName`, и такие имена являются различными, так как они чувствительны к регистру как и все идентификаторы в Java.

Используйте одинаковые имена: либо только `lastname`, либо только `lastName`.

Comment: благодарю, я до этого поста думал сменил, а оказалось, что нет, моя невнимательность :) буду в следующий раз внимательным, ещё раз благодарю за помощь